# Проводник по папкам и файлам, используя ASP Web API и AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

В моём solution есть 2 проекта. Первый - это WebAPI, где у меня есть классы:
FileClass для файлов, DirectoryClass для папок and ClassContext, который содержит List файлов и List папок. В HomeController у меня есть метод Get(string path)  и он возвращает экземпляр класса ClassContext. Потом эти данные конвертируются в JSON.
Мой 2 проект - простой Web Forms, где я использую AngularJS, чтобы показывать папки и файлы. Я очень долго шёл к получению этих данных и на данный момент нужные папки и файлы показываются.

Мой вопрос: я хочу кликать по папкам и чтобы сразу отображались её папки и файлы. Как мне это сделать, используя AngularJS или в дополнение к нему?

Код HomeController первого проекта:

```
public ClassContext Get(string path)
{
    List<string> directories = new List<string>();
    List<string> files = new List<string>();

    db.Directories = new List<DirectoryClass>();
    db.Files = new List<FileClass>();

    // checks if path is empty
    if (path.IsEmpty())
    {
        directories.AddRange(Environment.GetLogicalDrives());

        for (var i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++)
        {
            string str = directories[i];

            DirectoryClass dir = new DirectoryClass()
            {
                Name = str,
                Path = str
            };

            db.Directories.Add(dir);
        }

        return db;
    }

    DriveInfo drives = new DriveInfo(path);

    // checks if the logical drive is ready
    if (!drives.IsReady)
    {
        path = String.Empty;
        return Get(path);
    }

    // checks if there is a file with such path
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        OpenFile(path);

        var lastIndex = path.LastIndexOf("\\");
        path = path.Substring(0, lastIndex);
    }

    directories.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(path));

    // add directories
    for (var i = 0; i < directories.Count; i++)
    {
        string fullName = directories[i];
        var lastIndex = directories[i].LastIndexOf("\\");

        string name = fullName.Substring(lastIndex + 1);

        DirectoryClass dir = new DirectoryClass()
        {
            Name = name,
            Path = fullName
        };

        db.Directories.Add(dir);
    }            

    files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(path));

    // add files
    for (var i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
    {
        string fullName = files[i];
        var lastIndex = files[i].LastIndexOf("\\");

        string name = fullName.Substring(lastIndex + 1);

        FileClass file = new FileClass()
        {
            Name = name,
            Path = fullName
        };

        db.Files.Add(file);
    }

    return db;
}
```

Код View второго проекта:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="FilesController">
    <h3>Directories:</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="item in result.Directories">
    <a href="#">{{item.Name}}</a>
    </div>

    <h3>Files:</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="item in result.Files">
        <a href="#">{{item.Name}}</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
</script>
<script>
myApp.controller("FilesController", function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:55555/api/Home?path")        .success(function(response) {
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добавляйте обработчик клика, `ng-click` и загружайте то что нужно внутри него